# Why does countermonotonicity induce lower Fréchet–Hoeffding copula bounds?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, copula

I am learning [Copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) that describes dependancy between random variables.

The upper bound of Fréchet–Hoeffding is quite easy to understand. However, I do not understand the intituivie behind the fact that the *countermonotonic random varibles, not independent ones,* induce the lower bound.

In [this document (at the end of page 6)](http://www.angelfire.com/falcon/isinotes/mult/cop1.pdf), the author said that

> Certainly, independence is quite contrary to this, and for two independent rvs the copula
>   equals $C(u_1, u_2) = u_1 \cdot u_2$. However, independence just **serves as an intermediate step** on the
>   way to the contrary extreme of comonotonicity, namely the case of countermonotonic rvs. In terms of uniform rvs this case is obtained for $U_2 = 1 − U_1$.

Could anyone please explain how independence is only an intermediate step?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos done.